# Why does $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1 + \sqrt{m}}{2}]$ have the condition about parity?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

The ring of integers for $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{m})$ where $m$ is squarefree and $m \equiv 1 \mod{4}$ is defined to be $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1 + \sqrt{m}}{2}] = \{a + b(\frac{1 + \sqrt{m}}{2}): a, b \in \mathbb{Z}\}$. However, I have also seen that $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1 + \sqrt{m}}{2}] = \{\frac{u + v\sqrt{m}}{2}: u, v \in \mathbb{Z}, u \equiv v \mod{2}\}$. Why is it the case that $ u \equiv v \mod{2}$? Would $\frac{u + v\sqrt{m}}{2}$ fail to be an algebraic integer if $u \not\equiv v \mod{2}$?

Comment: $(X-\frac{u+v\sqrt{m}}{2})(X-\frac{u-v\sqrt{m}}{2})=X^2-uX+\frac{u^2-mv^2}{4}$. If $u,v$ have different parity, then $\frac{u^2-mv^2}{4}$ is not an integer, or equivalently $\frac{u+v\sqrt{m}}{2}$'s minimal polynomial has leading coefficient $4$.

Comment: The “deep” reason is that $(1+\sqrt m)/2$ is an algebraic integer iff $m-1$ is divisible by $4$.